# Sorting files into new folders based on first number using Applescript

Tags: sorting, applescript, delimiter, create-directory

I'm trying to make a folder that will automatically create folders then sort the files into them based on the first number. The files I have to sort all come in a similar format with a name like,***Feb 4 2.3 U#03 (3).mrd***. My intention was to write some AppleScript to create a folder based on the number (2.3) then put all the files with (2.3) into that folder, and do the same with all the other files.

I made a bit that sorts the files based on their number that seems to work,

```
set text item delimiters to {" "}
tell application "Finder"
    set aList to every file in folder "Re-namer"
    repeat with i from 1 to number of items in aList
    set aFile to (item i of aList)
    try
      set fileName to name of aFile
      set firstPart to text item 1 of fileName
      set secondPart to text item 2 of fileName
      set thirdPart to text item 3 of fileName
      set fourthPart to text item 4 of fileName
      set fifthPart to text item 5 of fileName
      set newName to thirdPart & " " & secondPart & " " & firstPart & " " & fourthPart & " " & fifthPart
    set name of aFile to newName
    end try
end repeat
end tell
```

now I just need to create the new folders based on the first number and put the matching files in. I tried to make a script for this too (keep in mind I've never coded before and have no idea what I'm doing) and unsurprisingly it didn't work :(

```
tell application "Finder"
open folder "Re-namer"
set loc to folder "Re-namer"
set aList to every file in loc
repeat with i from 1 to number of items in aList
    set aFile to (item i of aList)
    if not (exists folder named "text item 1" in loc) then
        make new folder in loc with properties {name:"text item 1"}
    else
        move aFile in folder "text item 1"
    end if
end repeat
end tell
```

I've found a few similar questions but I still can't get it to work. If anyone has any ideas or resoures to help with this question I would greatly appreaate it.

Comment: Your approach is OK for a beginner. Instead of saying open folder "re-namer" you should provide a path to that folder. I did not see a reference to it.

Answer (score 0):

Your are very close to correct script. However, instead of doing 2 loops, one for changing names and one to move files, it is quicker to do only 1 loop doing both at same time.

Also, the key thing is to understand that, in the loop, if you change the name, the Finder loose the reference to the file changed, then it fails when you try to move it after changing name. but since you know the folder and the new name, you can still reference to that "new" file.

```
set MyRenamer to choose folder "Select the folder"
set TPath to MyRenamer as string
set text item delimiters to {" "}
tell application "Finder"
    set aList to every file in MyRenamer
        repeat with F in aList
        set fileName to name of F
        set firstPart to text item 1 of fileName -- like "Feb"
        set secondPart to text item 2 of fileName -- like "4"
        set thirdPart to text item 3 of fileName -- like "2.3"
        set fourthPart to text item 4 of fileName -- like "U#03"
        set fifthPart to text item 5 of fileName -- like "(3).mrd"
        set newName to thirdPart & " " & secondPart & " " & firstPart & " " & fourthPart & " " & fifthPart
        set name of F to newName
        if (not (exists folder thirdPart in MyRenamer)) then
            make new folder in MyRenamer with properties {name:thirdPart}
        end if
        move (TPath & newName) as alias to folder (TPath & thirdPart & ":") -- rebuild the new file path as alias and move it.
    end repeat
end tell
```

Tested and OK.